# why CloudBuild using default service account instead of cloudbuild service account

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

When I push code to branch and trigger it by Cloud build GCP. It's throw below error:

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: You do not have permission to act as 'ProjectName@appspot.gserviceaccount.com'

- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo
  description: You do not have permission to act as this service account.
  resourceName: ProjectName@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
  resourceType: serviceAccount

It should Use Service Acccount:
15428174@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com

Below is my CloudBuild.yaml File:

steps:

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  args: ['package','-Dmaven.test.skip=true', '-Pdev']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy', '--appyaml=./src/main/appengine/dev/app.yaml']
  timeout: '1600s'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a security item. The App Engine instance has a service account assigned to it. You are using Cloud Build to deploy an application to App Engine. This error means that the account pushing the code to App Engine has not been granted the right to "use" the App Engine service account.

The purpose is to prevent you from elevating your permissions by deploying an application to a service with a service account that has higher/different permissions.

The solution is to grant the account the ActAs permission for the App Engine service account to the Cloud Build service account.

Comment: I am not using Default service account. I am using different service account which have below Role:
App Engine Admin
App Engine Creator
Cloud Build Editor
Cloud SQL Editor
Editor
Source Repository Writer
Storage Admin

I don't have any update on cloudbuild service account. Previously it was working fine but dont know why this fail

Comment: @parmendrak74 - The error message explains why. My answer explains why. Research how IAM works in regards to the `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` role.

Comment: How to resolve this issue.

Comment: I can deploy appengine manually but getting issue with CICD. because for CICD I am using non default service account.Which account need ActAs permissions,

Comment: I can deploy appengine manually but getting issue with CICD. because for CICD I am using non default service account.Which account need ActAs permissions,

Comment: What documentation did you read on the `ServiceAccountUser` role? That is your solution - add that role to the service account. To solve problems you need to invest in learning the basics. In your case how IAM works and how to apply roles to a service account. You can do this via the GUI (Google Cloud Console), via command line `gcloud` or via SDK/API.